# my own Class type not working well with MPI_scatterv and Gatherv

Tags: c++, class, struct, stdvector, openmpi

I have my own class `class2` in a `.h` file and i am using it to create a struct like the code below. (All the code is verified and complete)

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator> 
#include "class2.h"
#define MPI_CLASS2 MPI_FLOAT
using namespace std;


struct Pcle
{
    Class2 Pot;
    Class2 Vy;
    float   ss;
    Pcle(){}; //default empty constructor
    Pcle(float M, int Px, int Py) // constructor
    :Pot(Px, Py)
    , Vy(0.f, 0.f )
    , ss (M)
    {}
};
```

I will provide the `.h` file also if necessary. the problem is that logically, values passed throught both the `MPI_Scatterv` and `MPI_Gatherv`, at the end change (or some of them at least) and when i try changing from `Class2` to simply `int` type (and change the whole idea obviously) the code works fine. To have an idea here is my `main` file which produces good results with `int` instead of`Class2`

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int size, rank, chunk,j=0;
    int recvcount, part;

    vector<Pcle> in;
    vector<Pcle> c;
    vector<Pcle> f;

     MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
     MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

        MPI_Datatype MPI_PART, oldtypes[2];
        int blockcounts[2];

       // MPI_Aint type used to be consistent with syntax of
       // MPI_Type_extent routine
        MPI_Aint offsets[2], extent;

        MPI_Status stat;

        offsets[0] = 0;
        oldtypes[0] = MPI_CLASS2;
        blockcounts[0] = 2;

        // Setup description of the 1 MPI_FLOAT field, Mass
        // Need to first figure offset by getting size of MPI_Vector2
       MPI_Type_extent(MPI_CLASS2, &extent);
        offsets[1] = 2*extent;
       oldtypes[1] = MPI_FLOAT;
       blockcounts[1] = 1;

        // Define structured type and commit it
        MPI_Type_struct(2, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &MPI_PART);
        MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_PART);

    if (rank ==0){ //initalizing stuff in rank ==0
        part = 64;
        chunk = floorf(part/size);

        for (int i=0; i< part; i++){
            in.push_back(Pcle(i,2*i,2.5*i));
                      f.push_back(Pcle());
        }

     }
    //broadcasting needed variables
    MPI_Bcast(&chunk, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&part,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int sendcount[size];
   //creating the arguments for scatterv
   for(size_t ct = 0; ct<size; ct++){
         if (ct < part%size)
            sendcount[ct] = chunk+1;
        else
           sendcount[ct] = chunk;
    }

    int displs[size];

    displs[0]=0;

    for ( j =1; j< size; j++)
    displs[j] = displs[j-1] +sendcount[j];

    recvcount = sendcount[rank];


    c.reserve(recvcount);

    MPI_Scatterv(in.data(), sendcount, displs, MPI_PART, c.data(), recvcount, MPI_PART, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int iteration =0; iteration <10; ++iteration){

        //two functions which changes some of the data in Pot but leaves ss the same and can be left out
        MPI_Gatherv(c.data(), sendcount[rank], MPI_PART, f.data(), sendcount, displs, MPI_PART, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
    if(rank ==0)
        for (int k=0; k<64; k++)
            cout<<f[k].ss<<" ";

    MPI_Finalize(); 
    return 0;

}
```

The output of this code is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

the last few values remained zero which is wrong. I eliminated my class completely and tried running with an `int` type instead of `class2` in struct and other changed in code accordingly. the results were correct

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 Program ended with exit code: 0
```

With my knowledge I guess that I am not defining the class correctly to MPI. I am writing `#define MPI_CLASS2 MPI_FLOAT` with the preprocessor directives maybe there is something wrong with that.

here is the header file. with this, the code should be compiled and outputs replicated.

```
           #pragma once

 #include <math.h>
 #include <assert.h>

 struct Class2
 {

     union
     {
         float Element[2];
         struct { float X, Y; };
         struct { float U, V; };
     };

     Class2() {}

     Class2(float p_fValue)
     : X(p_fValue), Y(p_fValue) {}

     Class2(float p_x, float p_y)
     : X(p_x), Y(p_y) {}

     Class2(const Class2 &p_vector)
     : X(p_vector.X), Y(p_vector.Y) {}

     float operator[](int p_nIndex) const { return Element[p_nIndex]; }
     float& operator[](int p_nIndex) { return Element[p_nIndex]; }

     inline void Set(float p_x, float p_y) {
         X = p_x; Y = p_y;
     }

     inline bool Equals(const Class2 &p_vector, const float p_epsilon = 1e-5f) const
     {
         if (fabs(X - p_vector.X) > p_epsilon) return false;
         if (fabs(Y - p_vector.Y) > p_epsilon) return false;

         return true;
     }

     Class2& operator=(const Class2 &p_vector)
     {
         X = p_vector.X;
         Y = p_vector.Y;

         return *this;
     }

     inline bool operator==(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
         return Equals(p_vector);
     }

     inline bool operator!=(const Class2& p_vector) const {
         return !(*this == p_vector);
 }

     inline Class2 operator*(float p_fValue) const {
        return Class2(p_fValue * X, p_fValue * Y);
     }

     inline Class2 operator/(float p_fValue) const
     {
         assert(p_fValue != 0.f);
         return Class2(*this * (1.0f / p_fValue));
     }

     inline Class2 operator*(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
         return Class2(p_vector.X * X, p_vector.Y * Y);
     }

     inline Class2 operator+(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
         return Class2(X + p_vector.X, Y + p_vector.Y);
     }

     inline Class2 operator-(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
         return Class2(X - p_vector.X, Y - p_vector.Y);
     }

     inline Class2 operator-(void) const {
         return Class2(-X, -Y);
     }

     inline Class2& operator*=(float p_fValue) {
         return *this = *this * p_fValue;
     }

     inline Class2& operator*=(const Class2 &p_vector) {
         return *this = *this * p_vector;
     }

     inline Class2& operator/=(float p_fValue) {
         return *this = *this / p_fValue;
     }

     inline Class2& operator+=(const Class2 &p_vector) {
         return *this = *this + p_vector;
     }

     inline Class2& operator-=(const Class2 &p_vector) {
         return *this = *this - p_vector;
     }

     inline float MaxComponent() const {
         return std::max(X, Y);
     }

     inline float MinComponent() const {
         return std::min(X, Y);
     }

     inline float MaxAbsComponent() const {
         return std::max(fabs(X), fabs(Y));
     }

     inline float MinAbsComponent() const
     {
         return std::min(fabs(X), fabs(Y));
          }

     static Class2 Max(const Class2 &p_vector1, const Class2 &p_vector2)
     {
              return Class2(std::max(p_vector1.X, p_vector2.X),
                   std::max(p_vector1.Y, p_vector2.Y));
     }

     static Class2 Min(const Class2 &p_vector1, const Class2 &p_vector2)
     {
         return Class2(std::min(p_vector1.X, p_vector2.X),
                        std::min(p_vector1.Y, p_vector2.Y));
     }

     inline float Length(void) const {
        return sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
     }

     inline float LengthSquared(void) const {
         return X * X + Y * Y;
     }

   inline void Normalize(void) {
          *this = Class2::Normalize(*this);
   }

   inline float Dot(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
        return Class2::Dot(*this, p_vector);
   }

   inline float AbsDot(const Class2 &p_vector) const {
        return Class2::AbsDot(*this, p_vector);
    }

   static float Dot(const Class2 &p_vector1, const Class2 &p_vector2) {
        return p_vector1.X * p_vector2.X + p_vector1.Y * p_vector2.Y;
    }

    static float AbsDot(const Class2 &p_vector1, const Class2 &p_vector2) {
            return fabs(p_vector1.X * p_vector2.X +
                   p_vector1.Y * p_vector2.Y);
    }

    static Class2 Normalize(const Class2 &p_vector) {
        return p_vector / sqrt(p_vector.Length());
   }

    static float DistanceSquared(const Class2 &p_point1, const Class2 &p_point2) {
        return (p_point2 - p_point1).LengthSquared();
    }

    static float Distance(const Class2 &p_point1, const Class2 &p_point2) {
        return (p_point2 - p_point1).Length();
   }
};

inline Class2 operator*(float p_fValue, const Class2 &p_vector) {
    return Class2(p_fValue * p_vector.X, p_fValue * p_vector.Y);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal code that can be compiled and executed?

Comment: @HristoIliev I updatet the question with the code necessary to replicate my first result.

Comment: I would appreciate some feedback since i have been stuck on this for quite a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code is very confusing. You should not use the `MPI_` prefix for naming your own symbols as that prefix is reserved for the MPI implementation and doing so might result in name clashes with consequences very hard to debug. Then, you define `MPI_CLASS2` to be `MPI_FLOAT`, which is really confusing given that `Class2` is the name of a structure with multiple fields and not simply a scalar. Use `MPI_Type_create_struct` or `MPI_Type_contiguous` instead. Because `MPI_CLASS2` is `MPI_FLOAT`, the type map of `MPI_PART` does not correspond to the actual data layout and MPI incorrectly computes the offsets in both the scatter and the gather operations.

The simplest solution is to replace the definition of `MPI_CLASS2` with the following:

```
MPI_Datatype MPI_CLASS2;
MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_FLOAT, &MPI_CLASS2);
```

The more elaborate solution is to notice that the extent of the MPI datatype might not always match the true size of the language type, therefore computations such as `offsets[1] = 2*extent;` might not always work. It is advisable to instantiate an object instead and fetch the address of each field separately (or use the C standard `offsetof` macro from the `cstddef` header):

```
MPI_Datatype dt_class2;
MPI_Type_contiguous(2, MPI_FLOAT, &dt_class2);

MPI_Type dt_temp, dt_pcle;
MPI_Aint offsets[3], base;
int blockcounts[3];
MPI_Datatype oldtypes[3];

Pcle dummy;
MPI_Get_address(&dummy.Pot, &base);
MPI_Get_address(&dummy.Vy, &offsets[1]);
MPI_Get_address(&dummy.ss, &offsets[2]);

offsets[0] = 0;
blockcounts[0] = 1;
oldtypes[0] = dt_class2;

offsets[1] -= base;
blockcounts[1] = 1;
oldtypes[1] = dt_class2;

offsets[2] -= base;
blockcounts[2] = 1;
oldtypes[2] = MPI_FLOAT;

MPI_Type_create_struct(3, blockcounts, offsets, oldtypes, &dt_temp);
MPI_Type_create_resized(dt_temp, 0, sizeof(Pcle), &dt_pcle);
MPI_Type_commit(&dt_pcle);

MPI_Type_free(&dt_temp);
MPI_Type_free(&dt_class2);

// Now dt_pcle is ready to use
```

`MPI_Type_create_resized` is used to make sure that the extent of the MPI datatype matches exactly the size of the structure `Pcle`, which takes care of any padding that might get inserted by the compiler (non in your case as there are only `float`s).

Comment: when you say `MPI_Type dt_class2` you mean `MPI_Datatype` right? What you are saying completely makes sense and i am going to try it out. Although i managed to make the code work. But still there is not much speed up as i thought there would be in fact in some cases, using only one process was the fastest solution. maybe your code will help with that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a typo and must be `MPI_Datatype`. As for the speedup, that depends on your ability to split the work between the MPI processes. Communication adds to the overhead, so unless you are doing lots of parallelisable computation, you are unlikely to see gains from using MPI.

Comment: i am still happy with this code since the execution time is MUCH faster then using openMP or just sequential. it is just that increasing the number of processes does not do that much of a difference. for example with just 2 process or 4 i gained much more time then using openMP in general (this is an nbody problem). is that a normal thing with MPI? does it tend to take less time then openMP (speaking in general of course every situation is different)

Comment: oh and from `pcle dummy;` onwards thats inside the parralel code right? i.e. after that line code has to be inside `MPI_Init..` am i correct?

Comment: MPI is not faster *per se*. Properly parallelised applications can deliver the same speedup using either MPI or OpenMP (on a single node, obviously). As to the last question - yes.

Comment: lliev i actually implemented this and now the program is exiting "with exit code 3" which was not happening before. i haven't changed anything just your code.

Comment: lliev https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0YSKjfAagA1WjlHamVQNU01bmc uploaded here Thanks!

Comment: Providing a sample input file would help too.

Comment: The case is probably that I've omitted the mandatory `MPI_Type_commit` of `dt_pcle` and you haven't added it in your code too.

Comment: the input files is a csv files (as .txt)  I will provide it as well

Comment: Uploaded just now.

Comment: It was the missing call to `MPI_Type_commit`.